# Azure functions - visual studio fails to start

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am having problems trying to debug Azure Functions within visual studio using the azure functions tooling.
I've had it working in the past, (maybe a month ago) but for some reason its now not working.

I've tried restarting visual studio and creating a new azure function project totally clean and only change to a Timer Template Project I did was set the storage accounts in the appsettings.json

## AppSettings.json

```
    {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YYYAccountKey=XXX;",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YYY;AccountKey=XXX;"
      }
    }
```

## host.json

After it failed, I tried to add some content to the host.json from the github example which is the following

```
{
    "id": "9f4ea53c5136457d883d685e57164f05",
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": "api"
    },
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ],
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
      "batchSize": 16,
      "maxDequeueCount": 5,
      "newBatchThreshold": 8
    },
    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "autoRenewTimeout": "00:05:00"
    },
    "eventHub": {
      "maxBatchSize": 64,
      "prefetchCount": 256
    },
    "tracing": {
      "consoleLevel": "verbose",
      "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly"
    },
    "singleton": {
      "lockPeriod": "00:00:15",
      "listenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
      "listenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:03"
    }
}
```

But that doesn't help either.

## What happens

As I start debugging in visual studio, the command prompt window opens up and the Azure Functions Character logo appears and then a bunch of text is showed (very very quickly < 1 second), before the command prompt disappears.

Here is a link of a picture i managed to get when the window showed before closing

[image: console results]

## Full Console message

```
                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activat
ion of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registrat
ion: Activator = WebScriptHostManager (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft
.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lif
etime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> A h
ost ID must be between 1 and 32 characters, contain only lowercase letters, numb
ers, and dashes, not start or end with a dash, and not contain consecutive dashe
s.
Parameter name: value (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.ArgumentExc
eption: A host ID must be between 1 and 32 characters, contain only lowercase le
tters, numbers, and dashes, not start or end with a dash, and not contain consec
utive dashes.
Parameter name: value
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHostConfiguration.set_HostId(String value)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebHostResolver.CreateScriptHostCon
figuration(WebHostSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebHostResolver.EnsureInitialized(W
ebHostSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebHostResolver.GetWebScriptHostMan
ager(WebHostSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.AutofacBootstrap.<>c__DisplayClass0
_0.<Initialize>b__2(IComponentContext ct)
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<Register>b__0(IComp
onentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ForDelegate>b_
_0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(ICompo
nentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifeti
meScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`
1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration reg
istration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistratio
n registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registratio
n, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context,
Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext cont
ext, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type se
rviceType)
   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
 serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetSer
vice[TService](IDependencyResolver resolver)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebApiConfig.Initialize(HttpConfigu
ration config, ScriptSettingsManager settingsManager, WebHostSettings settings,
Action`2 dependencyCallback)
   at WebJobs.Script.Cli.Actions.HostActions.StartHostAction.<RunAsync>d__21.Mov
eNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WebJobs.Script.Cli.ConsoleApp.<RunAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please use the built-in function to upload photos instead of using third party providers

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your Dependency Resolver. Remove Autofac and do it manually.

On your screenshot, the second line displays:

"Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent..."

Autofac is one Dependency Injection Framework. I believe it's being used to inject dependencies into your Azure Function. As you're not familiar with that, I assume you're trying to use some kind of existing funcionality into your Azure Function Logic.

My best advice would be: add a new Azure Function and add functionality to it smoothly.

Comment: can you expand on this please. what is Autofac? i've googled it but I've never come across it in my time developer c# programs

Comment: I havent added anything at all. Simply created a "Azure Functions Project" in visual studio, then right click on the project and added "new azure function" and just picked one of the simplest templates from the options.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the folder you've used for your project doesn't have any spaces, dashes or special characters.

Currently, the folder name will override what is applied to the host ID and that might lead to this issue. This has been fixed in the CLI, but hasn't been released yet, so it will be addressed with the next update.

Comment: the host.json is posted above in the original post

Comment: Looked at your error and managed to completely miss your host.json. :)
Please take a look at the updated answer as this is likely what you're running into.

Comment: when you refer to folder name, do you just mean the last folder or the full path?
Mine is the currently -> 
C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestFunctionApp

Comment: Just the folder, which doesn't seem to be the issue in your case. Would you mind placing your project on a repo up on GitHub and sharing the link so I can try to repro this on my end? For some reason, something is triggering a host ID validation falure for you.

Comment: I have added it to github for you https://github.com/elmo61/testAzureFunctionProject Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for providing that. The code you've shared works as expected. What version of the CLI are you running?

Comment: i think i have a more underlaying problem with visual studio itself as trying to publish with webdeploy also fails on projects that otherwise work on other machines.